# Data structure and algorithm for Max/Min apple number search and update

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I have a few boxes storing apples, each box(n) has different number of apple(n). Now I wanna know whether there is an appropriate data structure and algorithm for these requirements:
1. find the maximum and minimum apple number storing in these boxes, and the related box number n.
2. Since the apple number in each box is changing, I wanna update apple(n). Obviously, it's the most convenient to use box number to access apple number.

Hope you guys can give me some advice. Thanks!!!

Comment: what is the first requirement? Can u elaborate and provide some examples

Comment: the 1st requirement is to find out the max and min apple number storing in these boxes, and find out the corresponding box number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can impose a tree structure on an array. The leaves of the tree are the array itself. The next level up has one node for each pair of array elements. The next level up has four descendants for each node, and so on...

```
       15

   13      14
 9   10  11  12
1 2  3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Here 1..8 might be the original data points, and the higher numbers show tree nodes that you can add. Now if you hold at each internal node the minimum and maximum value found amongst any of its descendants you will find the minimum and maximum value for the whole array at the root of the tree, and you can find the index involved by tracking down the tree to it, or by storing indexes as well as values. When you update a value at the leaves, you track up the tree, if necessary, to recalculate the minimum and maximum values stored at its parents. All of these actions take time O(log n) because that is the height of the tree.

As an example, suppose that the input data is 101..108. This will produce the following tree of maximum values, with the absolute maximum for the whole tree at the top:

```
                 108
       104                  108
  102        104       106       108
101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108
```

If you now change the value 104 to 109, you can see that you need only change the values up from here to the top of the tree to restore the invariants of the datastructure and get the new maximum at the top

```
                 109
       109                  108
  102        109       106       108
101  102  103  109  105  106  107  108
```

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your answer. Hope you can kindly explain it. My original method was red-black tree. However, that method can meet my 1st requirement. It's not efficient to update the apple number in each box.

Comment: I have added an example to clarify it.

Comment: Great!!! I think that's the best solution! However, one defect is that max and min can't be found simultaneously. Two trees have to be built, one for max, and one for min.

Comment: Is there a terminology to describe this method? It looks like the combination of divide and conquer and tree searching

Comment: I don't know of a name for it. I think it is more primitive than anything that has been given a name.

Answer (score 0):

Take an array of the size *n*:

[image: Just like this]

The array cells represent the boxes. Initially all the cells are filled with zeros( because initially there are no apples )

Initialize the array as:

*max=0, min=0, maxbox=0, minbox=0*

Now say, an input comes to add j(user input) apples to box i (0-indexed array and user input), then do the following: a negative j means to remove apples.

```
arr[i] = arr[i] + j;
if( arr[i] > max ){
   max = arr[i];
   maxbox = i;
}
if( arr[i] < min ){
   min = arr[i];
   minbox = i;
}
```

Whenever a user provides a new input, you can do the above and keep track of the boxes containing minimum and maximum apples.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: this of course can find out the max and min, and update is efficient. However, the initialization can not be zero. I think the non-zero initialization makes this question difficult.

Comment: there must be some kind of starting state. If there is a non-zero starting state, then iterate over the array once, to get the initial values of *max,min,maxbox,minbox*. Then proceed with the same logic as stated.

Comment: yes, I agree with you. However, iteration over the array is a brute force method. If the number of box is very large, that can be a catastrophe...

Comment: So, will there be some kind of magic by which you will know the initial state?? If you dont have the initial state, you have to iterate.... that's understandable...

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution would be **Heap sort** algorithm.

If treat all these boxes of apple having different different apples in it as **distinct numbers**.

Then by building Heap and then apply heap sorting will cost nlogn complexity. with which you can get Max as well as Min box.

*If just need to find Max or Min you just need to build heap. If you want to proceed further then you need to apply Heap sort algorithm.*

Comment: find max and min is just one of the requirements. Heap sort can find the max and min, however, the corresponding box number can't be found out.